# Server does not respond to Requests while File Download! Any solution?

Tags: php, download

The current PHP code being used is :

```
header("Pragma: public");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($file));
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\"");
header($_SERVER["SERVER_PROTOCOL"] . " 200 OK");
ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file);
```

But when I download some file, the website stops functioning. The browser is sending the requests but it does not get any response from the server. They are in Pending mode until the download is finished, but once the download is finished, the server sends the response and the website starts functioning again. Can you please give a solution for this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using file-based sessions, it could be the cause of your problems : when a script opens the session for a given user, no other script *(for the same user)* will be allowed to open that same session, to prevent concurrent writes.

Typical solution : close the session before doing heavy manipulations that don't require the session to remain opened.

For more informations about this, see the documentation of the [**`session_write_close()`**][1] function *(quoting a portion of a relevant sentence)* :

> session data is locked to prevent
> concurrent writes only one script may
> operate on a session at any time.